# Time between document and other ressources

Tags: google-chrome, networking, optimization, console

With the Developper Console of Chrome you can view on network panel how the ressources are loaded.

I would like to know why there is a space between the document loaded and the other ressources loaded ? And how can I reduce this space to speed up my page ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMti6.png

Thanks